# How to use XMLAGG with WITHIN GROUP and OVER(PARTITION BY ) clause

Tags: oracle

```sql
LISTAGG(abc.id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY abc.id) OVER(PARTITION BY bdd.id) Codes
```

I want to convert this `LISTAGG` to `XMLAGG` as `LISTAGG` gives error if value reaches above 4000 character.

I tried this way but giving syntax error

```sql
RTRIM((XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, abc.id || ', ')) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY abc.id) OVER(PARTITION BY bdd.id)).extract('//text()').getclobval(), ', ') Codes
```

Comment: There is no listagg function in mysql - correct the tags to attract the appropriate experts.(possibly oracle or pl/sql)

Answer (score 0):

> How to use `XMLAGG` with `WITHIN GROUP` and `OVER(PARTITION BY )` clause?

Summary - you cannot, the `XMLAgg` syntax does not support either of those clauses.

---

From the [`XMLAGG` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/XMLAGG.html#GUID-BCD1D755-5E26-4F73-BA22-521C30D275DA):

> [image: XMLAgg Syntax Diagram]
>
> `XMLAgg` is an aggregate function.

Which means that:

- `XMLAgg` does not support the `WITHIN GROUP` syntax and the `ORDER BY` clause is within the brackets of the function.
- `XMLAgg` is an aggregation function and does **NOT** have an [analytic version of its function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-E5372020-A6DA-44BF-93BE-DA8C3F74CD01) so you cannot apply a windowing clause and specify `PARTITION BY`.

---

If you want to use it as an aggregation function then you can use:

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(
          XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, abc.id || ', ') ORDER BY abc.id)
            .extract('//text()')
            .getclobval(),
          ', '
       )
       AS Codes
FROM   abc
       INNER JOIN bdd
       ON abc.bid = bdd.id
GROUP BY bdd.id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE abc (id, bid) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

CREATE TABLE bdd (id) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CODES |
| --- |
| 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XKnYwCT3)

Comment: Thanks For your Response . I want to use partition by or group by function or similar function inside XMLAGG only I can't use group by outside a window function because it will affect other results also and to the best of my knowledge partition by and group by function both are different they don't give same result in all cases.

Comment: @SwapneshSahu The question was "How to use `XMLAGG` with `WITHIN GROUP` and `OVER(PARTITION BY )` clause?" and, as stated in the answer, you cannot as it does not support that syntax. You are going to have to find a different solution because `XMLAGG` will not do what you want. Either don't use `XMLAGG` or work out how to use `XMLAGG` in something like a `LATERAL` join ... but we cannot help you with that as you have not provided a [MRE] (and we can only answer the question you have asked).